# How can you state how abstract interpretation gets around Rice's Theorem succinctly?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, decidability

At [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19538/what-is-the-goal-behind-abstract-interpretation-in-programming-languages), abstract interpretation has a nice in-depth look. However, I'd like someone to clearly and very precisely state how abstract interpretation takes the result of Rice's Theorem over the Turing-complete programming languages/Turing machines, and uses abstract interpretation to get similar results for decidability for non-trivial program properties; or, rather, how does abstract interpretation get around Rice's Theorem/the Halting Problem?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Any abstract interpretation will be sucessful only on a subset of programs, never on all. Therefore there's no conflict with undecidability.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be as clear and concise as possible, I'd try saying this

> Abstract interpretation may only *over-approximate* properties of programs: the *most precise* abstract value of a program $P$ may be $a$, but any *algorithm* for computing an abstract value will in general compute some value $a'\geq a$ for $P$ (possibly $\top$ in the worst case).

Answer (score 1):

This is logically redundant with the answers already given by Cody and Mikolas, but here's an intuition that might help.  The property that any abstract interpretation proves about a program is guaranteed to be correct, but sometimes this is because the answer it brings back is "I don't know".  That answer may be useless, but it isn't wrong.  Basically, if you want a decidable version of a decision problem, you have to add this third option, so that the possible results are not "yes"/"no", but "yes"/"no"/"I give up".